# Removing a header from RestSharp RestRequest

Tags: restsharp

Is there any way to remove a header from a RestSharp RestRequest?

Ive stumbled upon this issue in the project page, but cannot see it was ever applied:

https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/959

There is one suggestion to use request.Parameters.remove(), assuming with the header name as a parameter, but i don't see how that should correspond to removing a header.

I'm likely just confused, can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

The `Parameters` property of `RestRequest` is poorly-named.  It should be called `Headers` because that's all it is; a `List` of the request headers.  Therefore, to remove one or more headers from the request, you must first find the header in the list and then remove it with the `List.Remove()` method.

For example, this snippet removes every `Authorization` header from the request.  I used this to remove old and expired auth tokens from a request before adding a new one.

```
foreach (var oldAuthHeader in request.Parameters.Where(p => p.Name.Equals("Authorization", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToArray())
{
    request.Parameters.Remove(oldAuthHeader);
}
```

Comment: Right. It's a list of kvps with a bad name.

Comment: Parameters property isn't just headers. It could also UrlSegment, QueryString, Cookie, etc. Check enum RestSharp.ParameterType.

Comment: @YanF. are you speaking of these? http://restsharp.org/usage/parameters.html

Answer (score -1):

Faster implementation of Nathan's response.

```
var authParam = requestHeadersAdded.Parameters.Find(p => p.Name == "Authorization");
requestHeadersAdded.Parameters.Remove(authParam);
```

Instead of wrapping the LINQ .Where in a foreach loop, this only loops one time.

Comment: FYI the expression of a `foreach` loop is only evaluated once and so you can use a LINQ expression and it will only loop once.  Also you should avoid using `==` for string comparison and instead you should explicitly declare the `StringComparison` to use.